# Truncate zero characters from the end of a string

Tags: python, string, optimization, coding-style

It often happens that we need to truncate the end of a string by a certain amount. The correct way to do this is `my_string[:-i]`.

But if your code allows `i` to be `0`, this tuncate the whole string. The solution I generally use is to do `my_string[:len(my_string)-i]`, which works perfectly fine.

Although I have always found that a bit ugly. Is there a more elegant way to achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `my_string[:-i or None]`?

Because `-0` equals to `0`, maybe it is more elegent way to convert `0` into `None`, that's the solution above.

Comment: That is the kind of mindblower I was looking for. I'll let a few answers come in, but that is on point!

Comment: This is how slicing works. When you pass nothing, the default value treated by python is `None` which is equivalent to length of list. In order to get the same functionality, passing `None` as the `end` parameter will be your best bet

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest:

```
my_string[:-i] if i > 0 else my_string
```

Comment: Even though it's longer. I do find that one clearer and sometimes use it. But can we do both clearer and shorter?

Comment: Even shorter: `my_string[:-i] if i else my_string`

Comment: Unless you need compact and fast coding, I'll stay with [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): `Explicit is better than implicit.`

Comment: This the best answer in term of good practice. Although, I am really looking for shady "hacks"